# In Angular test, confused about the concept on a component that uses a service that uses HttpModule

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-services, angular-components

I am pretty new to Angular.

I am looking at the test after understanding how the framework operates.

I found that a component that uses a service and if that service uses HttpModule, the component test spec file also need to have the HttpModule imported. I don't really understand the concept behind.

I think a component that uses the module should not need to know how the service works, as it is kind of an encapsulated process that the service performs. And changing a service that doesn't change the api should not break the component as well.

If my understanding is correct, then if there is a component that don't use HttpModule at the very beginning of the development, then someone write a component base on that service, and both of the developer write tests. One day, the service developer decided to use the HttpModule but the component developer might not know, the test for the component will fail in this case.

Why do we need to get the HttpModule into the component spec file?

Edit:
example as follow

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

describe('UserComponent', () => {
  let component: UserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UserComponent ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,  // this line is need to pass the test
      ],
      providers: [
        DataService,  // because this service is using HttpModule
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Yeah sure, I will edit the thread now.

Comment: How could angular inject the http service in the service if the http module is unavailable? That said, you *can* provide a mock service, without dependencies, in the testing module used to test your component.

Comment: But the point is when I am just running the app, the Component don't need the Http to be loaded, it just need to load the Service, and the Service will load up the Http. Why do we need to do that in testing but not while running the actual app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide different `DataService` in your test, something like this:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UserComponent ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: DataService,  useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('data', ['someMethod']) }
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

and then you can test weather the component is correctly interacting with the service.

```
component.onClick();
expect(component.dataService.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

See [more examples here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>), and [in official docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-a-dependency).

Comment: I understand that I can provide different Service (usually Mock service), but what if I really want to test base on the original service, do I always import the HttpModule, it is quite weird to import the HttpModule.

Comment: Yea, if you want real service you have to provide it's dependencies, all of them. Things can get complicated at times if you don't isolate or stub/mock your services, [for example](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/248)...

Comment: Marking this as solution, because "Yea, if you want real service you have to provide it's dependencies, all of them." which answer my question. Would you mind adding it to the answer, as it seems easier for other to find out. Thanks!